# How to list all the commands available in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-managers

A `package.json` can have lot of commands and common ones are `npm start`, `npm test` but there are generally more commands.

Is there a way to list all the commands?

Currently I use `less package.json` but it has too much noise to show.

Comment: `npm run`? `cat package.json | jq .scripts`? Alternatively they may be listed in the README or other docs (e.g. project Wiki on GitHub).

Comment: `yarn run`, Parse json file with any node script and print "scripts" value

Comment: @jonrsharpe You don't need the `cat`, you can do `jq .scripts package.json`

Comment: @k0pernikus TIL, thanks, I've generally just piped stuff through it

Comment: I have added the tab-completion approach to my answer.

Comment: You can use this way: npm run-script
It returns all scripts you have on your package,.json

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use:

```
npm run
```

to list all commands. (Yarn also features similar functionality on `yarn run`.)

This behavior is made explicit in the help page of `npm help run`:

> ```
> This  runs an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object.  If no "command" is provided, it will list the available scripts.
> ```

---

To get a quick overview if you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed:

```
jq .scripts package.json
```

You can still pipe that subset to `less` if you need to

```
jq .scripts package.json | less
```

---

Furthermore, you can use tab completion via [npm-completion](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/completion.html) and then you should see a list of possible commands when hitting tab and completes the commands if there is only one option left.

You can set it up temporarily via

```
source <(npm completion)
```

Depending on your terminal, you can make it persistent behavior by adding to your relevant config file:

```
npm completion >> ~/.bashrc
npm completion >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Nice that you consider the `zsh` folks which should be a lot these "node-days".

Answer (score 7):

I am surprised nobody suggested the `to_entries()` func in jq , aka:

```
jq -r '.scripts|to_entries[]|((.key))' package.json
# output
lint
build:css
build:dev
build:node
build:release
```

Which basically means :

- pick the .scripts section of the package.json file
- use row output - `-r`
- convert the object of this to .key .value pair
- show the keys only

Answer (score 4):

Here's a minimalist approach using only node!

List only the available commands.

```
node -e "console.log(Object.keys(require('.' + require('path').sep + 'package.json').scripts || {}))"
```

List all the available commands and their target.

```
node -e "console.log(require('.' + require('path').sep + 'package.json').scripts || {})"
```

Taking it one step further, you can turn this into a run command!
In `package.json` add it to the *scripts*.

Example:

```
"scripts": {
   "ls": "node -e \"console.log(require('.' + require('path').sep + 'package.json').scripts || {})\""
}
```

Now you can `npm run ls` !

Comment: Bit complicated but I guess yet another way.

Comment: if you are using pnpm, you can switch the word "ls" with "all", and then you could run `pnpm all` instead of `pnpm run ls`. 2 words are better than 3.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! It just relies on `node` being available rather than a particular packages like `jq` so now i've got a function in my .zshrc file like:
`function listScripts () {node -e "console.log(Object.keys(require('.' + require('path').sep + 'package.json').scripts || {}))"}`